# Reserved DHCP Address, now can't access the interwebs

Tags: networking, dhcp

Pretty self-explainitory. Yesterday I reserved a DHCP address for one of my computers and now it cannot access the outside world. It can resolve domain names, but it cannot ping. This is probably fairly  low-level, but I am network-dumb. On the local network, everything works fine.

Comment: From where did you get the IP address, your ISP? your router?

Comment: Private block; router.

Comment: Does the router have access-controls/restrictions/blocking/etc. in place/active? You may need to either disable it or add an exception for the IP/MAC address of the system. If it worked correctly before, then I would guess that the IP address is new, so you have to add/change the exception for the new IP.

Comment: Will check that out and report back! Thanks :)

Comment: What's your OS, Windows, Unix, BS2000?

Comment: Windows. /10char

Comment: As you speak of a "local network", my question may sound dumb (as probably all other machines work fine) -- but did you try a `tracert` instead of a ping to see where it hangs? In case you don't know: [traceroute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute), speaking simplified, does ping "all hosts along the way to the target", so you get a report from each "point along the way" -- until you reach your target, or the route breaks.

Comment: It should be noted that an unsuccessful ping on a traceroute (* * *) does not necessarily mean that hop is unresponsive or problematic, many routers just drop pings.